# How to implement handle heartbeat

Tags: netty

I would like to implement a heartbeat that can be handled at my final handle in the chain.  Its purpose is to find out if traffic is idle and do something about it.  What is the best way to do it the 'netty' way?, or just add a timer in my final handler is the way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use the IdleStateHandler and IdleStateAwareHandler for this.

Comment: netty 4 does not have IdleStateAwareHandler, what is alternative?

Comment: Just use IdleStateHandler and react on the IdleStateEvent in the userEventTriggered(...) method

Comment: base on Norman instructions, I extends IdleStateHandler  and override userEventTriggered() method

Comment: Actually, there is no need to extends IdleStateHandler, just add an instanct of that class into pipeline. This will trigger userEventTrigger() in the final handler to get called

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can schedule a periodic task like this:

```
ctx.executor().scheduleAtFixedRate(...);
```

or:

```
channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate(...);
```

However, it is not aware of connection idleness, so you need to deal with it by yourself.